# Flutter Firestore Get a Map and generate objects out of it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello Guys I need help again,

I have stored two maps in one document in firestore.
[image]

Now I want to get those two maps and generate an object (CalendarEvent) out of each training.

```
    class CalendarEvent {
      final String title;
      final String id;
      final String date;
    
      CalendarEvent({this.title, this.id, this.date});
    
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        Map<String, dynamic> map = {
          'title': title,
          'id': id,
          'date': date,
        };
      }
    
      factory CalendarEvent.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    
        return CalendarEvent(
          title: 'null',
          id: 'null',
          date:'null'
        );
      }
    
    
    }
```

For each training I want to generate an object of CalendarEvents.
I tried several things, but I think im stuck.

```
Stream<CalendarEvent> getTrainings() {
return _firestore
    .collection('users')
    .doc('${_authentication.getUID()}')
    .collection('user')
    .doc('trainings')
    .snapshots()
    .map((doc) => CalendarEvent.fromJson(doc.data()));
    
}
}
```

At the moment, the factory constructor of CalendarEvent is called just one time because of one document.
Is there a possible way, to call the constructor 4 times (for each training in those two maps one time)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve will be easily reached if you restructure your data.

Old data structure

> users -> user_id -> user -> trainings -> data

New structure

> users -> user_id -> trainings -> training_id -> data

I removed 'user' as a collection so that 'trainings' becomes a collection because this will allow you to fetch all trainings for all users or for a particular user easily.

e.g for your first training data (i.e: training1630319465118756)

> users -> user_id -> trainings -> 1630319465118756 -> {name: 'Ok', date: 'August 30th, 2021'}

Then your getTrainings function becomes

```
Stream<CalendarEvent> getTrainings() {
  return _firestore
      .collection('users/${_authentication.getUID()}/trainings')
      .snapshots()
      .map((doc) => CalendarEvent.fromSnapshot(doc));
  // I used fromSnapshot above so that we can get the id of the document.
  // fromSnapshot function is shown below.
}
```

Change your CalendarEvent model to below

```
class CalendarEvent {
  final String title;
  final String id;
  final DateTime date;

  CalendarEvent({this.title, this.id, this.date});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(CalendarEvent instance) {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'title': instance.title,
      'id': instance.id,
      'date': fromDateTime(instance.date),
    };
    return map;
  }

  factory CalendarEvent.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return CalendarEvent(
      title: json['title'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as String,
      date: toDateTime(json['date'] as Timestamp),
    );
  }

  factory CalendarEvent.fromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = snapshot.data();
    json['id'] = snapshot.id;
    // after adding id, we call your fromJson function
    return CalendarEvent.fromJson(json);
  }
}

Timestamp fromDateTime(DateTime val) =>
    val == null ? null : Timestamp.fromDate(val);
DateTime toDateTime(Timestamp val) => val?.toDate();
```

Comment: Hi there,
Thank you for your answer. My database is actually structured as you described it. Here, however, I have the problem that every time the user looks at the calendar, all of the user's trainings have to be loaded. This leads to costs for the read operations. So my idea was to store a single document in Firebase so that I only have a single read.